# Apply !important to all JS styled ele. Good Idea or No?

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm having a little trouble setting a couple of styles on some checkboxes, for adverse reasons I don't have direct access to the css, or the HTML. However I can use Pure Javascript to influence my project.

I have built a basic function with the intention of styling all Checkboxes on my page with two styles. `float: left; & marginRight: 1em`. I've included a small snippet showing the results of my labour.

```js
function styleEl() {
  // get all elements...
  var bxSyl = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

  // console.log(bxSyl);

  [].forEach.call(bxSyl, function(bs) {
    // style elements...
    bs.style.cssFloat = "left";
    bs.style.marginRight = "1em";
  });
};

// call it...
styleEl();
```

```css
.editoropt {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  background: #0f0;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Ground Floor </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">First Floor </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Second Floor </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Third Floor</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
```

After testing, these js set styles are being ignored. Thus the source of the question.

> I know when setting `!important` I need to use setProperty like so;
>   `document.body.style.setProperty ("color", "green", "important");`

However, what if I were to add it to all the styles in one hit in my example using JS? Is it a good idea to do so? If not why?

If It is ok to use this approach how would I do so?

**Possible Answer**

```
// inject style
function ctSe() {
  var css = "input[type='checkbox'] { float:left; margin-right: 1em !important;}",
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }

  head.appendChild(style);
  console.log(head)
  console.log(style)
  console.log(css)
};

ctSe();
```

Comment: Throwing an `!important` into CSS usually just results in having to fix the same problem further down the line.  Find out why they're being ignored.

Comment: Don't use JS for this. It a job (and much simpler) for CSS. `!important` should also be avoided.

Comment: @James, even if I did find out, I couldn't correct the issue due to my access problem to the source files.

Comment: I don't mean you need to edit CSS etc, I mean find out why they're being ignored.  If you have element level access to add styles using js, anything you add on the element itself should "win" and not be ignored.

Comment: @dfsq, I understand what you are saying but again because of my access issue to source files it's pretty much my only option.

Comment: @James, interesting thought. I'll look into it.

Comment: You don't need sources, you need to overwrite styles with new styles. The the point of CSS (cascade).

Comment: @dfsq, I dont understand, you're saying using javascript to style elements is bad. (i.e. use .css to overwirte .css?) However, I cannot add new stylesheets or edit existing ones without using JS to do so. If I'm missing something please clarify.

Comment: You could make your selector more specific (if possible) to override the previous css.

Comment: You can inject `<style>...</style>` with new rules the will overwrite existing ones.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I completly forgot about that tag.  *Facepalm.

Comment: @dfsq, somthing like what I've edited into the question?

Comment: Yes, I would do something like this. Just maybe decouple CSS from style element creation: `ctSe("input[type='checkbox'] { float:left; margin-right: 1em; }")`.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for your input bro, I'll do some testing and update the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add inline styles via JS and they have higher priority than CSS already.

Comment: Didn't know this. Good to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important` should be avoided and is a measure of last resort in all cases. Generally, the inheritance in CSS will work perfectly well for almost all cases.

However, just occasionally, you need to force a property to a style other than the one inherited.

Typically, only override those properties that are misbehaving.

Putting `!important` on everything is ill-advised IMHO.

Comment: As mentioned in the original question I have no access to the Css files nor can I include css in any other manner than JS. Meaning I cannot tweak it nor can I add to it in the traditional manner. If a style is already set in a .css file, I speculate I would need to include `!important` to override the style using JS.